# Install WordPress with SQL database

Tags: database, installation, sql

I am very new to WordPress. I didn't even know it existed until I had to do it for my work. So I started in with a WAMP server with WordPress. That worked fine until we needed multiple sites with WordPress, so I had to move it over to IIS. That still had MySQL involved and the CTO of the company wants it to run on SQL instead. I have Installed a fresh copy to mess around with from here "wordpress.org/ wordpress-3.4-IIS.zip" then I downloaded and installed [db-abstraction](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-database-abstraction/). That done, I extracted them to the location I wanted (wordpress/[site]).

1. Log into your current site and export your data as an xml file
2. Disable all your current plugins
3. Back up your existing `config.php` file
4. Download the plugin package.
5. Upload `wp-db-abstraction.php` and the wp-db-abstraction directory to `wp-content/mu-plugins`.  This should be parallel to your regular plugins directory.  If the mu-plugins directory does not exist, you must create it.
6. Put the `db.php` file from inside the `wp-db-abstraction.php` directory to `wp-content/db.php`
7. Visit `$your_wordpress_url/wp-content/mu-plugins/wp-db-abstraction/setup-config.php` to generate your `wp-config.php` file
8. Install WordPress
9. Log into the newly installed system and import your data
10. Reinstall and test your plugins

Up to step 6 it works fine. Then when I try and go to the php page, 1) I can't set the database type from MySQL to SQL 2) about 50% of the time I get a 500 error.

I really don't know if this makes any sense to anyone. I'm sorry if I am confusing you as it really confuses me as well. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate on your objective, namely "multiple sites". WordPress has functionality that allows you to run multiple sites with one code base (try searching for WordPress Multisite").

Comment: By multiple I mean on multiple servers to intergrate with our current website data that runs on coldfusion with SQL-T database.

Comment: Similar questions on StackOverflow: ["Wordpress MSSQL Installation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629048/wordpress-mssql-installation), ["Wordpress with SQL Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574698/wordpress-with-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

**Install WordPress Locally**

WordPress is well-known for its ease of installation. Under most circumstances, installing WordPress is a very simple process and takes less than five minutes to complete. If you wish to install WordPress on local, the following guide will help.

Before install WordPress Checking to ensure that you and your web host have the [minimum requirements](https://www.wpseeds.org/wordpress-setup/minimum-requirements-to-run-wordpress/) to run WordPress.

**Step 1: Download WordPress**

Download the WordPress package to your local computer from http://wordpress.org/download/.
Unzip the downloaded file to a folder on your local computer.

**Steep 2: Create MySQL Database and User**

WordPress stores its information in a database. Therefore, a database will need to be created.

Log into phpmyadmin i.r http://localhost/phpmyadmin/.

For Step 1: Create A Database.

For Step 2: Create Database Users, enter the database user name and password .

For Step 3: Add User to the Database, click the All Privileges checkbox .

For Step 4: Complete the task, make note of the database name, username and password, as you will need them for next step.

**Step 3: Configure wp-config.php**

The wp-config-sample.php file contains the database information and tells the WordPress application which database to pull information from. This step must be completed to ensure the correct database information is associated with the WordPress installation.

The wp-config-sample.php file can be found in folder where WordPress is installed. To modify the file:

Go to folder where WordPress is installed
From the folder, open wp-config-sample.php in a text editor
Right click on the file, select Rename and change the name of the file to wp-config.php.
Right-click on the wp-config.php file and select Code Edit. When the file opens, look for the following information:

define(‘DB_NAME’, ‘database_name_here’);/** MySQL database username */

define(‘DB_USER’, ‘username_here’);/** MySQL database password */

define(‘DB_PASSWORD’, ‘password_here’);

Replace database_name_here with the name of the database you created (above in step).
Replace username_here with the username of the database you created.
Replace password_here with the password of the database that you created.
When done editing, click the Save Changes button, then close the file.

**Step 4: Run the Installation**

Open a new browser window and go to the installation page to run the installation script. Depending on where you installed the script, you will find it at either of the following URLs:

Loading following URL into your web browser:

http://localhost/wordpress/wp-ad...

Be sure to replace wordpress in the example above with your actual folder name.

You should now see a welcome page that says “Welcome to the famous five minute WordPress installation process!”

**Step 5: Complete the Installation**

On this page, fill in the fields for:

Site Name

Username

Password (needs to be entered twice)

Email address (login information will be sent to this email address)

Select whether or not to have the search engines index the site

Click Install Now, and you should be taken to the final screen, showing the success message

For more information check : [Installing WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)

Comment: The question was about installing Wordpress with SQLServer.